# Dockerfile pull from nexus repository

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nexus, nexus3

My dockerfile points to a private nexus repository
`FROM nexus-repo/image:latest`
when i try and build i get a`Could not build image: received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable`

I am logged in beforehand, and running `docker pull nexus-repo/image:latest` works okay. What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: If not already tried, can you log out and log back in to your registry and they try? Has worked for me in the past

Comment: @aman_novice tried this and no luck

Comment: make sure the certificates are correctly configured https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#get-a-certificate

Comment: @EfratLevitan i dont think its certificates as i can push and pull, just not in dockerfile, if the certificates were wrong, i wouldnt be able to do either of these

Comment: are you running behind a proxy or VPN?

Comment: nope, just a hosted docker repository on nexus